# "IllegalStateException: Same jobid in systemuid." when scheduling a new job

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

It seems that more often than not, when trying to schedule a job using `JobScheduler`, I get the following error and the job doesn't start:

```
2018-11-16 08:59:58.740 912-4220/? E/JobScheduler: jobid:20536
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Same jobid in systemuid.
    at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService.scheduleAsPackage(JobSchedulerService.java:888)
    at com.android.server.job.JobSchedulerService$JobSchedulerStub.schedule(JobSchedulerService.java:2592)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
    at com.android.server.backup.FullBackupJob.schedule(FullBackupJob.java:54)
    at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$3.run(BackupManagerService.java:1925)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

The code I use to schedule the job inside an activity's `onCreate()` is like this:

```
JobScheduler js = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
js.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(123, new ComponentName(this, TestService.class))
        .setMinimumLatency(5000)
        .build());
```

What could cause this error? It doesn't seem to matter which ID I pass to the `JobInfo.Builder()` constructor - it's always the same 20536 mentioned in the stack trace.

Comment: refer this link http://www.zoftino.com/android-job-scheduler-example

Comment: @AndroidTeam there wasn't a single mention of the issue on that page.

Comment: In this link mention similar code like  JobInfo jobInfoObj = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
        .setMinimumLatency(500).setOverrideDeadline(300).build();

Comment: It's not about this issue. Please refrain from commenting tangential stuff.

Comment: @manabreak did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem lately

Comment: @manabreak have tried by mentioning some other id i mean instead of `JobInfo.Builder(123` why don't you use `JobInfo.Builder(11123`